# fastest way to persist changes

Tags: database, caching, memcached, persistent-storage

in my web app the database has a blob(an xml file). The user is allowed to change the blob through a web interface. I take the blob show it in a html form, then the user can change some values and save it back. So the user submit request has a db save. Can I save the entry to a cache to speed up the submit request? But then there is a chance of loosing the changes? What is the fastest way to persist the blob in db?

Answer (score 0):

You can queue the save for a later time. While there is a some chance that the user will lose his changes it is negligible compare to the benefits.

Comment: we do this in some cases where the save can be deferred. But if it has to persist for sure then what to do?

Comment: @anony Then you need to implement async method.

Comment: what are the various ways to do this async?

Comment: @anony Well thats depends on you stack